# keep going off-axis on big jumps i don't know how to stop it?

Tags: technique, jumping

I've been riding for about 5-6 years, and can speed through tech, can do hips, speed-jumps 5-8 meters... but every time theres a jump with a steep lip, or involves me going quite high, i keep coming off-axis/ tilt mid-air and its starting to mess with my confidence, desperately need help how do i stop this, and jump normally?

Comment: Have you had any coaching, if not, that will be your best option.  If its messing with your confidence, park the ego and go back to basics, go small, 100% right, 100% of the time, 100% confident and relaxed before progressing back to bigger jumps.

Comment: Which axis specifically?

Comment: To the side... so if u we’re looking from infront of my handle bars I’d be rotating clockwise/anti-clockwise

Comment: About 8 months late to the party but:
Are you riding with platform pedals or SPD pedals? (My rear-most/stretched leg pulls my bike off-axis when using SPD pedals)
Are the off-axis always to the same side?